# Is it possible to send an email and auto redirect in single php file?

Tags: php, email, redirect, header

As the title said:

Is it possible to send an email (using php mail()) and after sending the email, auto redirect to another page. All the codes will be in single php file?

Code-wise, should be something like this:

```
if(mail(argument...)){
    header("Location: www.google.com");
}
```

I think I would get a: "Error: header information already sent" or something like. But what if I want to send email and then auto-redirect on that page?? Possible?

Comment: You know, paraphrasing the error does nothing for us. Could you not copy and paste the full error? It's much more helpful. That error should tell you the exact line and file where the output was started.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error:

```
Error: header information already sent
```

usually caused by having white space before the opening and closing PHP tags or something was printed to the browser before preparing the page.

If this is the only code you have

```
if(mail(argument...)){
    header("Location: www.google.com");
}
```

it will work because you are not printing anything to the browser but be sure to avoid including white spaces.

Comment: Note: If the white space is after the closing tags then it won't matter because the script will have already executed.